How to elegantly map over deep iterables?
I have an iterable of tuples Iterable[tuple[int, str]].  I would like to map over this, and only edit the second item of each tuple.  This, unfortunately, leaves me with a lot of boilerplate for un-packing and re-packing the first element of each tuple:
map(lambda t: (t[0], do_something(t[1])), my_iterable)

In the spirit of functional programming, I actually have lots of these small functions that I would like to apply sequentially to the second part of these tuples:
map(
  lambda t: (t[0], bar(t[1])),
  map(
    lambda t: (t[0], foo(t[1])),
    map(
      lambda t: (t[0], do_something(t[1])), 
      my_iterable)
    )
  )
)

The repeated un-packing and re-packing of t[0] feels clumsy.  Is there a better way to do this? Is there a solution that generalizes more complex data structures?

bar(foo(do_something(t[1]))) is not viable?

@matszwecja In my use case, the individual mappings are actually broadly useful.  So, the bar map, the foo, bar map, and the do_something, foo, bar map are all being used individually, and everywhere they are used there is a dangling t[0].

In that case, why bother with t[0] at all? Unpack, do stuff on t[1], if and when you need original structure, pack it again,

@matszwecja This is one option.  I like that the tuple structure enforces a length constraint: for every t[0], there is a t[1].  I could design all of my functions around keeping these entirely separate: f(t0s:Iterable, t1s:Iterable).  I agree that this would clean up most of this packing/unpacking.  I would upvote such an answer.

You are essentially treating the tuples as functors in the Haskell sense; your function only touches the second element. As such, you can define an appropriate tuple-map function:
def tuple_map(f):
    return lambda t: (t[0], f(t[1]))

map(tuple_map(bar), 
    map(tuple_map(foo),
        map(tuple_map(do_something),
            my_iterable)
        

Further, you can take advantage of the functor law and compose your functions and only use map one time.
def f(x):
    return  bar(foo(do_something(x)))

map(tuple_map(f), my_iterable)


For readers unfamiliar with the functor laws, it basically says that, given
def compose(f, g):
    return lambda x: f(g(x))

the following holds for functors like iterables:
map(f, map(g, iterable)) == map(compose(f, g), iterable)

(That's one of the two functor laws. The other is simpler: map(lambda x: x, iterable) == (lambda x: x)(iterable), i.e., mapping the identity function over the iterable is the same as applying the identity function to the iterable.)
Tuples are functors in the sense, not of being iterable, but if being a single value "tagged" with multiple other values. A tuple like (3, 4, 5) is not seen as an immutable list, but as the number 5 with associated values 3 and 4. Whatever you do to 5, 3 and 4 remain unchanged.
